# How to get mesh object size as pixel (not Vector3) in Babylonjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pixel, mesh, babylonjs

### babylonjns

---

In a React app, how to get mesh object size as pixel (not Vector3) using Babylonjs?

I tried this:

```
       let meshPixelSize= meshObject.getBoundingInfo().boundingBox;
```

Comment: Does it help you?

let meshPixelSize= meshObject.getBoundingInfo().boundingBox.extendSize;

 console.log("meshPixelSize");
     console.log(meshPixelSize);

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But it returns Vector3 , not pixel. I need pixel size of mesh.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone looking for the answer for this question, this is the function to calculate mesh object size in pixels.

```js
function calculatePixel(obj) {
    //note: "engine" is your babylonjs engine variable
    //note: "camera" is the camera variable, optionally you can pass the camera as function parameter (change this function to accept second parameter)
    const temp = new BABYLON.Vector3();
    const vertices = obj.getBoundingInfo().boundingBox.vectorsWorld;
    const viewport = camera.viewport.toGlobal(engine.getRenderWidth(), engine.getRenderHeight());
    let minX = 1e10, minY = 1e10, maxX = -1e10, maxY = -1e10;
    for (const vertex of vertices) {
        BABYLON.Vector3.ProjectToRef(vertex, BABYLON.Matrix.IdentityReadOnly, scene.getTransformMatrix(), viewport, temp);
        if (minX > temp.x) minX = temp.x;
        if (maxX < temp.x) maxX = temp.x;
        if (minY > temp.y) minY = temp.y;
        if (maxY < temp.y) maxY = temp.y;
    }
    //console.log("maxX-minX",(maxX-minX));
    //console.log("maxY-minY",(maxY-minY));
    return {"x":(maxX-minX), "y":(maxY-minY)}
}
```

calling example: `calculatePixel(meshObject[1]);` //don't forget the [1]

source: https://playground.babylonjs.com/#DWPQ9R#240

credits goes to: Evgeni_Popov from babylon.js forum (discussion: https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/get-size-of-mesh-relative-to-canvas/19738)